# UNION causes "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to int"

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, union, varchar

I tried to search for previous articles related to this, but I can't find one specific to my situation. And because I'm brand new to StackOverflow, I can't post pictures so I'll try to describe it.

I have two datasets. One is 34 rows, 1 column of all `NULL`s. The other 13 rows, 1 column of `varchar`s.

When I try to `UNION ALL` these two together, i get the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value  to data type int.

I don't understand why I'm getting this error. I've `UNION`ed many `NULL` columns and `varchar` columns before, among many other types and I don't get this conversion error.

Can anyone offer suggestions why this error occurs?

Comment: The literal `null` is given a datatype of `int`. You probably need to `cast` it as `varchar`. Table definitions? Code?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code you are using and the layout of the table.  A small example is best.

Comment: what datatypes are the NULLs in your table?what happens if you wrap them in CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),YourColumn)) before unioning them?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The error occurs because you have corresponding columns in the two of the subqueries where the type of one is an integer and the type of the other is a character.  Then, the character value has -- in at least one row -- a value that cannot be automatically converted to an integer.

This is easy to replicate:

```
select t.*
from (select 'A' as col union all
      select 1
     ) t;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/20937) is the corresponding SQL Fiddle.

SQL Server uses pretty sophisticated type precedence rules for determining the destination type in a `union`.  In practice, though, it is best to avoid using implicit type conversions.  Instead, explicitly cast the columns to the type you intend.

EDIT:

The situation with `NULL` values is complicated.  *By itself*, the `NULL` value has no type.  So, the following works fine:

```
select NULL as col
union all
select 'A';
```

If you type the `NULL`, then the query will fail:

```
select cast(NULL as int) as col
union all
select 'A';
```

Also, if you put SQL Server in a position where it has to assign a type, then SQL Server will make the `NULL` an integer.  Every column in a table or result set needs a type, so this will also fail:

```
select (select NULL) as col
union all
select 'A';
```

Perhaps your queries are doing something like this.

Comment: I have also encountered this error when a column contains varchar values that are mostly  numeric strings such as '20546' the view is queried with said column being compared to an integer instead of the string representation of the integer.

Comment: Gordon, I believe your edit hits the mark. My NULL columns were inside a subquery. Yes, I know subquery are not a good practice but I had a reason for doing them. Since the NULL column was in a subquery and I queried them again, SQL Server would assign them a datatype before executing the union, so it assigned int. Not sure why I didn't run into this problem before, but I will look at it again today. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I have also encountered this error when I accidentally had the fields out of sequence in the 2 SELECT queries that I was unioning.  Adjusting the fields' sequence fixed the problem.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32038481)