# conversion data type error while unioning

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to union 29 very large tables in SQL server and I'm getting the error message "conversion failed when converting the varchar value '10-p4' to data type int. I would prefer not to comb through all the columns in all the tables. I also can't find information on what '10-p4' means. How can I get my union to work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Union causes "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to int"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373180/sql-union-causes-conversion-failed-when-converting-the-varchar-value-to-int)

Answer (score 1):

For a union to work ,all columns must be of same data type..

This will fail

```
select 1,'a'
union
select 'b','c'
```

This will work if you are in version >=2012

```
select 1,'a'
union
select try_Cast('b' as int),'c'
```

so try using try_Cast if you are in a version >=2012 for the column throwing the error

for versions >=2008 and <2012,you also can try sql_variant,since it encapsulates all datatypes

```
   select cast(1 as sql_variant),'a'
union
select cast('b' as sql_variant) ,'c'
```

you could also try eliminating offending value, if you believe you have only ints by using isnumeric in where clause,but this is subject to some limitations

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example

```
select 1 
union 
select '10-p4'
```

You will get the same error when you execute the above query. A column can be of only one `datatype`. You cannot combine `Int` and `Varchar`. If you do so the compiler will implicitly convert the `varchar` to `int` datatype because `INT` has higher precedence over `varchar`

With the given information this all I can comeup with, figure out which column has `'10-p4'` data and do a explicit conversion of `INT` to `Varchar` to avoid Implicit conversion

```
select cast(1 as varchar(10))
union 
select '10-p4'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are likely trying to use union to combine tables with different data types. One table contains the value '10-p4' somewhere, but another table has a column with the same name declared as int.

Answer (score 0):

A union of 29 tables? Ouch - performance must suck! You'd be better off creating a temp table with the correct schema at the start of your query, inserting records into it in 29 subsequent inserts and then selecting the contents back out.

Asides from being more performant (sql doesn't have to compare 29 resultsets to see if it can find a common schema) it's also much easier to debug your SQL

Here's a sample:

```
-- Ensure that the temp table does not already exist 
-- (irrelevant if you wrap this in a stored proc)
if (object_id('tempdb..#tempTable') is not null)
    drop table #tempTable 

-- Create a table in the tempdb to compile your results in
create table #tempTable
(
    SourceQuery int,
    Foo varchar(100),
    Bar int
)

-- Fill the temp table
insert into #tempTable
select 1, foo, bar
from TableA

insert into #tempTable
select 2, hellp, world
from TableB

-- 27 more queries like this

-- Get your results
select * from #tempTable

-- Tidy Up
drop table #tempTable
```